# Is it wrong/bad to use more than one canvas (not at the same time) in a program?

Tags: java, canvas, awt, frame

So I am pretty new to java and programming (4 months) and I am trying to make a basic snake game with a menu. I am switching between each different component by adding and removing them on the frame. Here is the code:

```
public class screen extends Frame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static screen f;
private static menu ex;
private static loadsettings settings;
public screen(String frameLabel, int width, int height) {
    setSize(width, height);
    setLocation(50,50);
    setResizable(true);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);  
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    settings = new loadsettings();      
    f = new screen("Game", settings.getWindowWidth(), settings.getWindowHeight());
    ex = new menu(f,settings); 
    f.add(ex);
    ex.createBufferStrategy(2);
    ex.requestFocus();
}
public static void new1Player(){
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.removeAll();
    player1 ex = new player1(f,settings);
    f.add(ex);
    ex.createBufferStrategy(2);
    ex.requestFocus();
}
public static void new2Player(){
    f.setSize(600,600);
    f.removeAll();
    player2 ex = new player2(f,settings);
    f.add(ex);
    ex.createBufferStrategy(2);
    ex.requestFocus();
}
public static void newMenu(){
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.removeAll();
    menu ex = new menu(f,settings);
    f.add(ex);
    ex.createBufferStrategy(2);
    ex.requestFocus();
}
}
```

The thing is, each component is a Canvas, so they are constantly being added and removed. I just want to know, is this bad coding and is there a better way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Not much of a game programmer, but I've heard using multiple canvas elements is beneficial if you want to prerender a frame/sprite that will be used often. Then you can simply keep that canvas offscreen and copy it to the viewport instead of rendering this element many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about using the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

> A CardLayout object is a layout manager for a container. It treats
>   each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at
>   a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards. The first
>   component added to a CardLayout object is the visible component when
>   the container is first displayed.

You can use a Canvas if you like, but theres no reason you couldn't just use Panels.